# How to position a box after another one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I am using both Bootstrap and Masonry plugins in my website.
At the top I have a bar by Bootstrap and then there a box for Masonry plugin. To problem is the Masonry plugin goes uder the top bar. I gave it `margin-top:50` but then it gives a horizontal scroll bar.

Here is the code & Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f3f7kdv2/)

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* inherit height from window */
 html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
/* ---- isotope ---- */
 .isotope {
    background: #DDD;
    height: 100%;
    /* inherit height from body */
}
/* clear fix */
 .isotope:after {
    content:'';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

If you check the demo, the first box has an image and that shows the middle box is under the top bar. The middle div must have 100% height, to make sure Masonry plugin works.
So how to avoid the top and bottom divs to not overlap the middle div?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `padding: 50px` to the `body` element?

Comment: @TwiStar well yh mate, worked. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have changed some class properties. Try change those and see.

```
.isotope {
    z-index:100000;
    background: #DDD;
    height: 80%;
    /* inherit height from body */
    top: 45px;
}

.item.height2 {
    height: 263px;
}
```

Here's JSFiddle [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f3f7kdv2/4/).

Comment: Thanks mate, but where are the bars ? they disappeared. also no space from top

Comment: @Dan I modified the isotope class.. take a look!